# ¿Como recorrer los registros de un dataset en C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy creando una aplicación, y en una de las ventanas para ver los registros que hay en la base de datos, al momento de dar clic en los botones de navegación me arroja un error

El error que lanza es:

> 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

jUEGOViewSource fue null.

Es la primera aplicación que hago en WPF, tal vez sea algo sencillo pero no veo en donde esta.

El  código es el siguiente:

```
    public partial class VerJuegos : Window
    {
        public VerJuegos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Variables para la vizualización de los registros y navegar entre ellos
        private GAMERGABDataSet gAMERGABDataSet;
        private GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapterManager;
        private System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource jUEGOViewSource;


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            GAMES.GAMERGABDataSet gAMERGABDataSet = ((GAMERGABDataSet)(this.FindResource("gAMERGABDataSet")));
            // Cargar datos en la tabla JUEGO. Puede modificar este código según sea necesario.
            GAMES.GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapters.JUEGOTableAdapter gAMERGABDataSetJUEGOTableAdapter = new GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapters.JUEGOTableAdapter();
            gAMERGABDataSetJUEGOTableAdapter.Fill(gAMERGABDataSet.JUEGO);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource jUEGOViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("jUEGOViewSource")));
            jUEGOViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }




        //Este método hace regresar a la ventana opciones
        private void BtnVolver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Opciones opciones = new Opciones();
            opciones.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        //Este método es para navegar entre los juegos
        private void BtnAtras_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (jUEGOViewSource.View.CurrentPosition > 0)
            {
                jUEGOViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToPrevious(); //Aqui me genera el error
            }
        }

        //Este método sirve apra nevagar entre los juegos
        private void BtnAdelante_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (jUEGOViewSource.View.CurrentPosition < ((CollectionView)jUEGOViewSource.View).Count -1) //Aqui me genera el error
            {
                jUEGOViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error te sale porque no inicializas el objeto `jUEGOViewSource` que has declarado global, sino que estas inicializando otro objeto con el mismo nombre y del mismo tipo en local en el evento `OnLoad`. Dicho evento debería quedar:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    GAMES.GAMERGABDataSet gAMERGABDataSet = ((GAMERGABDataSet)(this.FindResource("gAMERGABDataSet")));
    // Cargar datos en la tabla JUEGO. Puede modificar este código según sea necesario.
    GAMES.GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapters.JUEGOTableAdapter gAMERGABDataSetJUEGOTableAdapter = new GAMERGABDataSetTableAdapters.JUEGOTableAdapter();
    gAMERGABDataSetJUEGOTableAdapter.Fill(gAMERGABDataSet.JUEGO);
    jUEGOViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("jUEGOViewSource")));
    jUEGOViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ElGerar, eso era lo que me estaba afectando